# Does Microsoft Edge have a Continue-on-the-SmartPhone Option?

Tags: android, bash, windows-10, cygwin, microsoft-edge

I have an Olden Bourne-Again SHell-Script (BASH) that I have been using for the last five years with great success under the CygWin Environment in the Microsoft Windows 10 Operating System.

The Shell-Script does some tricks and then it proudly pops up a Web-Browser: Chrome or Firefox or Internet Explorer or Opera or Safari.

Now, what I want to do is to make the BASH Shell-Scripting Environment pop it up inside the Android PS on a smartphone.

I want to do it the Microsoft way. My idea is to use Microsoft Edge that should have a Continue-on-Phone Option. It should.

On the smartphone in the Android OS, I have installed the Microsoft Launcher application and the Microsoft Edge browser

Now, I am trying to tell the CygWin Environment to flip a coin and to make it seen on the smartphone. Here is my code:

```
cygwin_starter="/usr/bin/cygstart.exe"
browser_executable="/cygdrive/C/System32/cmd.exe
/C C:\Windows\explorer.exe
shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe
!MicrosoftEdge"
$cygwin_starter "$browser_executable" $tested_address
```

I am getting all kinds of weird errors, similar to the following ones:

```
Unable to start 'C:\System32\cmd.exe \C
C\Windows\explorer.exe
shellAppsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe
!MicrosoftEdge':
The specified file was not found.
```

I have tried with and without the `cygstart.exe`, with and without the `cmd.exe`. I am sure that there are lots of people out there who have been riding this kind of bike for a long time already.

Update:

I am just pasting here the Current State of this Minor Modification so that things get clearer and clearer.

There are no more Software Errors!

This is the Minor Modification of the `random.sh` `B.A.SH.` Shell-Script File in the `Notepad++` Textual Editing Software Application:

```
edge_starter="C:\Windows\explorer.exe
shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge
$tested_address"
edge_batch_file="Edge.BAT"
echo $edge_starter > $edge_batch_file
cygwin_starter="/usr/bin/cygstart.exe"
browser_executable="/cygdrive/C/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /K $edge_batch_file"
$cygwin_starter $browser_executable
```

I have intentionally inserted above some nice carriage return characters so that you can see the code beautifully on narrow displays.

The CygWin Terminal Window shows a Clean Slate without any Software Errors:

```
dobre@Draupadi
/cygdrive/g/Root/Freelancing/8_Software_Development/GitHub_Projects/Random

$ ./random.sh
_____________________________________________________________________
The script has run for 0 hours, 0 minutes, and 46 seconds.
It has tested 2 addresses.
The found address is:
https://www.amruta.org/1990/08/17/
_____________________________________________________________________
Press any key to continue...d

dobre@Draupadi
/cygdrive/g/Root/Freelancing/8_Software_Development/GitHub_Projects/Random
$
```

The `C:\Windows\System32\CMD.EXE` terminal window is presenting this output:

```
G:\Root\Freelancing\8_Software_Development
\GitHub_Projects\Random>C:\Windows\explorer.exe
shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge
https://www.amruta.org/1990/08/17/

G:\Root\Freelancing\8_Software_Development\GitHub_Projects\Random>
```

Then the Documents window is popped up instead of Microsoft Edge.

If I take out the `$tested_address` parameter that is given to it, then I get it right. That is, I get Microsoft Edge, but without the desired web page. That is, I get a blank Microsoft Edge page.

Update:

I think that I have finally got it right. The command line is just one and it is as simple as the following one:

```
/usr/bin/cygstart.exe /cygdrive/C/Windows/System32/cmd.exe
/c "start microsoft-edge:$tested_address"
```

Now I get my desired web page in Microsoft Edge, but I do not find the Continue-on-the-SmartPhone option. It has a Share menu, but I cannot see the Android-powered smartphone in it so that I can send the Web-Page to it.

Update:

I have researched a little bit more and it appears that the Continue-on-the-SmartPhone option has not been implemented yet and I am simply just rushing too fast into the near future.

I have tested the Continue-on-PC feature from the Android-powered smartphone and it is working nicely. The web page that is sent from the smartphone nicely pops up in Microsoft Edge.

I have expected that a Continue-on-the-SmartPhone option should already be implemented, but it does not seem to be the case. I can find a cast option, but that is not the same thing. One can somehow cast parts of his screen, the whole web browser (Chrome or Microsoft Edge), tabs from them or even the full screen to another electronic device, but this does not sound to be the same case as my desire to pop up only a web page in a web browser using an Option such as the imagined Continue-on-the-SmartPhone Option.

Comment: Nicely composed question, however... _"C:\System32\cmd.exe"_ - you do know _Windows OS_ is not _Linux OS_, right? If so, why are you asking this kind of question?

Comment: First of all, does this command work as you expect when you execute it in the Win 10 command window? If you can get that to work, you should be able to wrap that command in a .bat file which cygstart can start.

BTW: are you using the cygwin setup to keep your install up to date? That is step 0.

Comment: I suggest you to use the script that can be understand by the Android OS. You need to check first whether this code is supported under Android or not. Then you can see that you had pass the paths like windows OS, Which I think not present in your Android device and due to that reason you are getting an error for file not found error. Also Android OS not use the '.EXE' file. Generally it use '.APK' file. So I think you need to change many things. You also need to understand the difference between the working of Windows and Android.

Comment: Updating is my middle name, @Doug Henderson. You can think of me as `Mihai Updating Dobrescu`. I have nicely and recently updated the Full Software Installation of the `CygWin` Development Environment to a Size of around `100` Giga-Bytes. The `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge` Command nicely starts the `Microsoft` `Windows` `Edge` Web-Browser when it is run from the `Run` Window. Why does it start that `Documents` Window when it is run from within the `/usr/bin/cygstart.exe` Process?

Comment: Your idea to use a `.BAT` Batch File is great, @Doug Henderson. Instead of using the `/C` Switch, I am using the `/K` Switch and that starts the `CMD.EXE` Process, then it runs the Batch File and then it proudly presents the `Microsoft` `Windows` `Edge` Web-Browser to the Stupified User. However, if I attempt to also point it to a certain Web-Page, then it reverts back to the Situation when it presents the `Documents` Window. It is getting trickier and trickier. However, there are no errors and I am getting happier and happier.

Comment: I think that - for the moment - the Automation Process will stop at the Opening of the `Microsoft` `Windows` `Edge` Web-Browser on the Laptop Personal Computer Machine, @deepak-MSFT. If I succeed in performing that then I shall get back to your `Microsoft` Expertise and ask you how to Manually `Continue-on-the-SmartPhone` the Web-Page that is opened in the `Microsoft` `Windows` `Edge` Web-Browser so that I get it in the `Microsoft` `Edge` Web-Browser that is launched by the `Microsoft` `Launcher` Software Application on the `Google` `Android` Operating System that is running on the SmartPhone.

Comment: Please only use quotes when necessary, and only tag text as code when it is code.